# What slider is used on stackexchange homepage?

Tags: jquery, sliders

What slider is used to scroll through the sites on the Stackexchange website? I think it's Anything Slider but can't seem to find where and how it is implemented.

Can anyone show me an example of it or another script that does similar?

Thanks in advance.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean - http://grab.adrianfraguela.com/e6ds

Comment: Looks like anythingSlider. http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/js/home.js?v=3a6605ce6125

Comment: http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/js/home.js?v=3a6605ce6125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like anythingSlider. [cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/js/home.js?v=3a6605ce6125](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/js/home.js?v=3a6605ce6125)

Comment: +1 for going out there and finding it out for him ;-)

Comment: Nice thanks, do you know where there is a tutorial or example of how it is coded similar to this one? Been searching for a while and can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely is anythingSlider.

The container div has a class of `anythingSlider`

and the home.js file included in the `head` has the anythingSlider javascript in it.